# How to add multiple classNames to an html element when using scss in React

Tags: reactjs, sass, styles, class-names

I have a `styles.module.scss` file and a react component. How can add multiple classNames from the styles to ONE html element?

Below is my code:

`/styles/styles.module.scss` file

```
.gridContainer {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2em;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 25em;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.gridItem {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.imageWithText {
  border: 1px solid #4338ca;
  border-radius: 1.6rem;
  align-self: start;
}
```

`/pages/infoPage.tsx` file

```
import styles from "../styles/styles.module.scss";

export default function InfoPage({}: PageProps) {
  <div className={styles.gridContainer}>
    <div className={styles.gridItem}>
      ...
    </div>
    
    {/* I have added TWO style selectors here */}
    <div className={(styles.gridItem, styles.imageWithText)}>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

When I run this code, the `div` with TWO style selectors does not work as expected. The second `classname={styles.gridItem}` does not take the scss styles from the `.gridItem` selector. This `div` takes the styling only from the `.imageWithText`.

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR**: I want the styles for both the `.gridItem` and the `.imageWithText` to apply to the second `div`.

I believe I am not writing the multiple selectors in the html element correctly and this has possibly got something to do with the way `scss` works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the .gridContainer works, .gridItem should work. And to apply both style to the second div, you can use classnames npm package.
...
import cx from 'classnames';
...
className={cx(styles.gridItem, styles. imageWithText)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with backtic character (`), so your code :

```
 <div className={`${styles.gridItem} ${styles.imageWithText}`}>
```